# What's the number of ways to order a 3-dim pile?

Tags: combinatorics

I get inspired on observing the remaining available cups near a coffee machine of my department. Every morning the 36 cups are neatly placed in the right corner of a shelf as a 6 by 3 by 2 cuboid. When picking a cup, everyone follows the rule as if they were told so:

- *Never take a cup that is on-the-right-of/behind/below another one*.

This makes me wonder how many possibilities are there to take all of these cups. Indeed we can formulate the problem in the following model:

> Let M,N,L be positive integers, and X={(a,b,c) : 0<a<M+1, 0<b<N+1, 0<c<L+1}. Based on the following partial orders:
>
> 1. (a_1,b,c)<(a_2,b,c) if a_1<a_2,
> 2. (a,b_1,c)<(a,b_2,c) if b_1<b_2,
> 3. (a,b,c_1)<(a,b,c_2) if c_1<c_2,
>
> how many total orders can be defined?

I have computed two special cases: L=1 and M=N=2. Please let me know your ideas on the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Amazingly, this is a complicated problem with a very nice solution! The rectangular stack of cups where no cup has an empty space behind/to the right of/below itself (except at the very back/right/bottom) is known as a [*plane partition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition). To count the number of shapes, you need to count the number of plane partitions which fit in a $6\times 3\times 2$ box. The solution to the problem of counting plane partitions fitting in an $a\times b\times c$ box is written in *Combinatory Analysis*, by Percy MacMahon, and is
$$
N_1(a,b,c)=\prod_{i=1}^{a}\prod_{j=1}^b\frac{i+j+c-1}{i+j-1}
$$
In your case, the number is
$$
N_1(2,3,6)=\frac71\cdot\frac82\cdot\frac93\cdot\frac82\cdot\frac93\cdot\frac{10}4=2520
$$

Comment: Uh, the formula does not look symmetric about a,b,c. Are you sure N_1(a,b,c)=N_1(b,c,a)? Also, As I can exhaust, N_1(2,2,2) should be 48, but your RHS is 20 (the factor with a=b=2 is not an integer).

Comment: @JPan It doesn't look symmetric, but surprisingly it is. It can be equivalently written as $$\prod_{i=1}^a\prod_{j=1}^b\prod_{k=1}^c\frac{i+j+k-1}{i+j+k-2},$$revealing the symmetry (the first way is better for computation). $\tag*{}$ I think $N_1(2,2,2)$ is correct. I count $6$ arrangements with four cups on the bottom layer, $5$ with three on the bottom, $6$ with two on the bottom, $2$ with one on the bottom, and one with zero on the bottom. How do your arrangements break down based on number in the bottom layer?

Comment: Let's use (a,b,c) with a,b,c =0 or 1 here. The first is always (0,0,0). Then the second and the third can only be chosen from (1,0,0), (0,1,0), and (0,0,1) --> 6 possibilities. Suppose it's (1,0,0) and (0,1,0), and then there's bifurcation for the fourth.

Comment: Situation I: Fourth being (0,0,1). Then the 5-7th must be chosen from (1,1,0), (1,0,1), and (0,1,1), which is 3!=6 possibilities. The 8th is always (1,1,1).

Comment: Situation II: Fourth being (1,1,0). Then the fifth can only be (0,0,1). 6-7th chosen from (1,0,1) and (0,1,1) --> 2!=2 options.

Comment: To wrap up, in total we have 6 times (6+2) = 48 ways to go.

Comment: @JPan I see. I did not realize that you were considering the ordering in which you take the cups as relevant; the formula in my answer only counts the number of shapes of the cups. Let me continue to think...

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion.